# event.passThroughOnException sends requests to origin, but without POST data

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I thought that `event.passThroughOnException();` should set the `fail open` strategy for my worker, so that if an exception is raised from my code, original requests are sent to my origin server, but it seems that it’s missing post data. I think that’s because the request body is a readable stream and once read it cannot be read again, but how to manage this scenario?

```js
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.passThroughOnException();
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event));
});

async function handleRequest(event: FetchEvent): Promise<Response> {
  const response = await fetch(event.request);

  // do something here that potentially raises an Exception
  // @ts-ignore
  ohnoez(); // deliberate failure

  return response;
}
```

As you can see in the below image, the origin server did not receive any body (`foobar`):

[image: example in worker playground]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known limitation of `passThroughOnException()`. The Workers Runtime uses streaming for request and response bodies; it does not buffer the body. As a result, once the body is consumed, it is gone. So if you forward the request, and then throw an exception afterwards, the request body is not available to send again.

Answer (score 1):

Did a workaround by cloning `event.request`, then add a try/catch in `handleRequest`. On `catch(err)`, send the request to origin using `fetch` while passing the cloned request.

```js
// Pass request to whatever it requested
async function passThrough(request: Request): Promise<Response> {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(request)

    // Make the headers mutable by re-constructing the Response.
    response = new Response(response.body, response)
    return response
  } catch (err) {
    return ErrorResponse.NewError(err).respond()
  }
}

// request handler
async function handleRequest(event: FetchEvent): Promise<Response> {
  const request = event.request
  const requestClone = event.request.clone()
  let resp

  try {
    // handle request
    resp = await handler.api(request)

  } catch (err) {
    // Pass through manually on exception (because event.passThroughOnException
    // does not pass request body, so use that as a last resort)
    resp = await passThrough(requestClone)
  }

  return resp
}


addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Still added passThroughOnException here 
  // in case the `passThrough` function throws exception
  event.passThroughOnException()
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event))
})
```

Seems to work OK so far. Would love to know if there are other solutions as well.